# Parallax Banner using css or javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I am learning to create Parallax banner ad using CSS or javascript, I am inspired by this demo here [Parallax banner](https://demo.adocean-global.com/preview/75/1/) on scroll on right side u will see a banner appear, I want to create the same banner using CSS or js,

Js Fiddle Demo : [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yku0Lsqe/1/)

[image]

so far here is what I have tried

```css
/* Content Parallax Section*/
.ParallaxContent {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2581e8;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2581e8b0;
    padding: 42px 0;
    color:#FFF; 
} 
.ParallaxContent h3{
  color:#FFF;   
  text-align:center;
}


/* Video Parallax Section*/
.ParallaxVideo{ 
  max-width: 932px;
  max-height: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px; 
}
video{ 
  width: 932px;
  height: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  z-index: -9999;
}
.ParallaxVideo h3 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 76px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* General Section*/
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:0 12px;
}
.headlines h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "PT Sans",sans-serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.headlines p {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
  color:#f6f3f3;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <!-- Top Navigation -->
    <div class="cctop clearfix"></div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="ccparallaxeff">
            <div class="ParallaxVideo">
                <video autoplay muted loop>
                    <source src="videos/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
                </video>
                <h3>Video Background</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="ParallaxContent">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="headlines">
                        <h3>Responisve Design</h3>
                        <p>Work on all major devices</p>
                    </div>
                    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac dapibus dolor. Donec est elit, pellentesque eleifend risus euismod, mattis semper risus. Vestibulum dignissim, velit lacinia viverra bibendum,
                        turpis nisi consequat odio, in rhoncus est purus a sem. Praesent orci velit, laoreet vitae ornare quis, pretium non nibh. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia
                        Curae; Nullam quis volutpat mi. Donec cursus tincidunt quam vitae convallis. Nullam sollicitudin erat at nisi porttitor tristique. Nulla non eros eget nulla accumsan malesuada vitae eget tellus. Sed ut mauris
                        ut dolor tincidunt fringilla et nec lorem. Phasellus non lacus sodales arcu vestibulum gravida. Fusce eu massa nisl.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

What do I need to do to get the same banner as this demo [Parallax Banner Demo](https://demo.adocean-global.com/preview/75/1/#)